# Is BRIN a good index for a row modification timestamp?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a column

```sql
ALTER TABLE foo
ADD COLUMN modified_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

which is modified by a trigger

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_set_timestamp()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.modified_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER set_timestamp BEFORE UPDATE ON foo FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_set_timestamp();
```

Is the [BRIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/brin-intro.html) index a good alternative for the standard BTREE index in that case?

Comment: Do your queries use the BRIN index Yes or No? Use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) to get the result. Personally I never had success with this type of index but that says a lot about my work and probably nothing about BRIN.

Comment: Yes, because there is no any other index on that column and `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` show gains. I want to index these value to speed up manual queries in the db and I am just wondering, if that is the good case. The queries are invoked rarely and the reduced disk usage and less work on writes are promising in my case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Emphatically, no. A BRIN index will never work for a table that receives updates. You will have to use a B-tree index.

Comment: Which is to say that BRIN relies on disk blocks physically adjacent to each other on disk having adjacent timestamps too. Updates are extremely likely to break that connection and it doesn't take many exceptions to make your brin index useless.